# Where do I find the version of a Linux kernel source tree?

Tags: linux

I have downloaded from a hardware vendor just a tarball of their Linux source tree (no Git repository metadata), is there a way to find out the version number of the kernel?

Is the version number usually stored in a file somewhere in the source tree?

I'd like to be able to do this without compiling and running the kernel.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can find the version by running

```
make kernelversion
```

In the source tree

Comment: I should have clarified that I want to be able to do this just by examing the source tree rather than attempting to compile an run the kernel if possible. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @downvoters I have no problem with downvotes but it would be nice if you explain why please :-)

Comment: Adrian, I _suspect_ it was when you had the `uname` solution which would require installing the kernel. In any case, since you now have one that _doesn't_ require a build and install, here's an upvote for you to counteract the drive-by downvote - I hate them with a vengeance :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks and probably true - since the OP also edited his question the uname thing became the `wrong` answer. I just wish people would say - oh well :-)

Comment: Looking at the question edit history, `uname` was always the wrong answer (the question implied that the hardware to run the kernel might not even be available).  But from the original question I would have thought that something that inspected the build outputs would have been acceptable.

Comment: maybe you should add 'make kernelrelease' for the full releasenumber into you're solution

Answer (score 126):

Check the top-level `Makefile`, an example of which is [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/Makefile?v=linux-2.6). At the top of that, you should see something like:

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 1
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION = -pax
NAME = Custom Pax Version
```

The (admittedly minor) advantage of this method is that you only need the ability to view the files themselves rather than having to run a build process.

Comment: both methods are very good (I mean **make kernelversion** as well as **vi Makefile**) as in result before making any module or something depending on the kernel running now it's important to verify if command **uname -r** will match the output of **make kernelversion** and if not to modify with **vi Makefile**

Comment: The *major* advantage of this method is that you don't need to clone a  large repository just to check the version, when said version is not guessable from the git tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution: in the older times `include/linux/version.h`, currently `include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h`, but only after at least a partially successful compilation.

Comment: `include/linux/version.h` is deprecated, it now gets generated during a build in `include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h`

Answer (score 2):

In the Linux source tree's root file, check the Makefile content.
In its beginning part:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
VERSION = 4
PATCHLEVEL = 14
SUBLEVEL = 67
```

Then you linux source tree's version is: 4.14.67

Answer (score 2):

In case someone needs to script it: With `awk`, the version can be printed from `Makefile` like this:

```bash
awk '/^VERSION =/{a=$3};/^PATCHLEVEL =/{b=$3};/^SUBLEVEL =/{c=$3};/^EXTRAVERSION =/{d=$3};END{print a"."b"."c d}' Makefile
```

If the `EXTRAVERSION` appendix shall be skipped:

```bash
awk '/^VERSION =/{a=$3};/^PATCHLEVEL =/{b=$3};/^SUBLEVEL =/{c=$3};END{print a"."b"."c}' Makefile
```

*If someone knows how to make `awk` continue with the next pattern if the current pattern has been matched once, that would make it failsafe in case multiple lines start with `VERSION =` respectively. But I haven't seen this in any Linux source code version.*

Answer (score 0):

```
In the kernel source tree, check the root directory Makefile to get the kernel version as below.

Example as below:

 $ head Makefile
 # SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
 VERSION = 5
 PATCHLEVEL = 18
 SUBLEVEL = 0
 EXTRAVERSION = -rc3
 NAME = Superb Owl
 # *DOCUMENTATION*
 # To see a list of typical targets execute "make help"
 # More info can be located in ./README

From the above we get the source code version is 5.18.0-rc3
```